# ColdFusion 11 DateFormat

Tags: coldfusion, date-format, coldfusion-11

I am moving one of our applications from ColdFusion 9.01 to ColdFusion 11 and encountered a situation where I cannot get the date formatted the way I want it using "DateFormat". I read through the docs since things have changed in CF versions, but I honestly can't figure out why this isn't working. It worked beautifully in CF 9. I know it's probably something very easy, but I am just not seeing it.

The query (Oracle DB) provides me a list of the last 30 days and the loop is simply to reformat the date output from  "2014-07-01 00:00:00.0" to a more friendly looking display of 01-Jul-2014 except that I cannot get it to format as "dd-mmm-yyyy" it just spits back the original output from the query. I hard coded the date where normally there would be a cfquerparam. Any ideas?

```
<cfquery name="qryDateArray" datasource="#request.db#">
  select trunc(to_date('07/01/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') + 1 - rownum) as ref_date
  from dual connect by rownum <= 30
</cfquery>

<cfloop from="1" to="#qryDateArray.recordcount#" index="j">
  <cfset qryDateArray.ref_date[j] = DateFormat(qryDateArray.ref_date[j], "dd-mmm-yyyy")>
</cfloop>

<cfoutput>
  <cfdump var="#qryDateArray#">
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: is that a typo? i see a miss-matched `(` in your query.

Comment: My guess would be that the query results are readonly ( i always thought they were anyway ), so my first test would be to simply output the result of `DateFormat(qryDateArray.ref_date[j], "dd-mmm-yyyy")`

Comment: Thanks. It was a typo, I fixed it. I will go check the result without using cfset.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there a specific reason you need to update the query?  Usually you leave values as date objects, and only format them as strings on display.

Comment: There is a reason. The result set is used as input to other queries. I could change all the other queries to accept the unmodified date input, but since this date query drives a lot of others, it makes sense for me to fix it in one place. Otherwise I would leave the dates as they are.

Comment: *this date query drives a lot of others* Not sure I follow why that makes a difference. If the values involved are "dates" (not strings), there should not be any issue matching.

Comment: The dates are also used in Oracle "pivot" queries where the dates end up being column names. The dates from that small query end up serving two purposes; one to query the data, and secondly as column names where they have to be strings. So at some point they eventually have to be converted to a readable format and  it made sense to do that formatting in one place  - using a single query and then looping over the results to format it the way it was needed for both applications of using the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not test this on CF11 since I do not have it handy.  I did verify that your code though returns results as you explained when I ran it on my CF10 environment here.  So what you can do is add a column to the query object and define it as a varchar and add your formatted data to that.  This in turn dumped out the formatted dates.

```
<cfquery name="qryDateArray" datasource="#request.db#">
  select trunc(to_date('07/01/2014', 'mm/dd/yyyy') + 1 - rownum) as ref_date
  from dual connect by rownum <= 30
</cfquery>

<cfset aryData  = [] />

<cfloop from="1" to="#qryDateArray.recordcount#" index="j">
  <cfset ArrayAppend(aryData, DateFormat(qryDateArray.ref_date[j], "dd-mmm-yyyy")) />
</cfloop>

<cfset QueryAddColumn(qryDateArray, "STRDATE", "VarChar", aryData) />

<cfoutput>
  <cfdump var="#qryDateArray#">
</cfoutput>
```

[image]

If dependent on the query column names then could use something like Ben's method explained here to do some renaming of the columns:  http://www.bennadel.com/blog/357-ask-ben-changing-coldfusion-query-column-names.htm

Comment: Thanks so much for this. It worked perfectly. Thanks to you I can cross this little issue off of my list.

Answer (score 1):

It'd be great if you'd given us a portable test case rather than one that relies on your database, but I suspect it is because ColdFusion has become more rigid with its type management of query columns.

So CF considers your `ref_date` column to be of type date, so when you try to put the formatted string back into the query column, CF tries (and succeeds) to convert the string back into a date.

Aside:

I have to wonder why you don't format the data string in the DB from the outset, and just return it the way you need it, rather than returning something else, then looping over the thing to adjust it..?

Comment: Thanks Adam. The input for the query (the date) comes from an html form and is how the users enter it. That's why it's formatted as dd/mm/yyyy - for end user consumption. I will go back and review the entire data flow from start to finish. I was hoping there was an easy syntax fix I was missing, but it looks like it will make more sense for me to go back over the whole process rethink a better solution instead of spending my time on reformatting the date via cfset/cfloop. Thanks for your input.